# NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_select_rjs'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following examples in "Agile Web Development with Rails" fourth edition.  I'm on the section 11.5 Testing Ajax Changes.

Developing on:
Ubuntu 11.10
RVM|ruby 1.9.3|rails 3.1

This is the strange error:
    test_should_create_line_item_via_ajax(LineItemsControllerTest):
    NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_select_rjs'

This is the code from line_items_controller_test.rb

```
test "should create line_item via ajax" do
assert_difference('LineItem.count') do
  xhr :post, :create, :product_id => products(:ruby).id
end

assert_response :success

assert_select_rjs :replace_html, 'cart' do
  assert_select 'tr#current_item td', /Programming Ruby 1.9/
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The book is working with an old version of Rails.

See the documentation for [assert_select_rjs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select_rjs.). Right at the top it says:

> **Method deprecated or moved**
>
> This method is deprecated or moved on the
>   latest stable version. The last existing version (v2.3.8) is shown
>   here.

`RJS` in general works very differently in Rails 3. See here: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/21/jquery-new-default

This method is now available in `ActionDispatch`: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select_rjs

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine

Answer (score 0):

`assert_select_rjs` was [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select_rjs) for ActionController but is still part of [ActionDispatch](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select_rjs).

Comment: Thanks guys, two questions... 1. Is there a recommended alternative to using assert_select_rjs in rails 3.1?  2. If I was to use ActionDispatch, how do I go about doing that?  What's the code look like?